# Can you stretch font sizes while maintaining the same height?

Tags: html, css, css-grid, font-size, typography

I am using a CSS Grid layout that has 2 rows and 1 column, inside of it, I placed a word that will occupy almost the entire view-port `font-size:23rem;`. I am trying to replicate [this](https://www.udiscovermusic.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Unity.jpg) music album cover using only CSS and HTML. First in relation to my question I have two rows and in the starting row, or top row, I am placing two letters "U" and "N", if you look closely, the **N** is stretching more than its partner, the letter **U**, thus touching the other words, and if you go back to the U's lower end you can see this one is not touching the letter beneath, which is the **T**.

Since they both appear to have the same height and alignment on the axis, how can I successfully replicate the cover? Should I go for SVG text or draw the pattern for these on SVG? What would be the case if CSS couldn't replicate this?

[image]

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
}

p {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.unity-cover {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 2fr 2fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "start-row"
    "end-row";
    justify-items: center;
}

.start-row {
    grid-area: start-row;
    display: flex;
}

.end-row {
    grid-area: end-row;
    display: flex;
}

.letter {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 1px;
    font-size: 23rem;
}

.letter-u {
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    top: 27px;
}

.letter-n {
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
    right: 0px;
}

.letter-i {
    height: 300px;
}

.letter-t {
    height: 300px;
}

.letter-y {
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    right: 40px;
}
```

```html
<body>

        <ul class="unity-cover">
            <div class="start-row">
                    <li class="letter letter-u">U</li>
                    <li class="letter letter-n">N</li>
            </div>

            <div class="end-row">
                    <li class="letter letter-i">I</li>
                    <li class="letter letter-t">T</li>
                    <li class="letter letter-y">Y</li>
            </div>


        </ul>

</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean by the 'N is stretching more than its partner'? Stretching is which direction and is the 'U' its partner?

Comment: i would say that first to apply css and tune it to your needs, be sure you have a valid HTML structure .. cause `<ul class="unity-cover"><div class="start-row"><li class="letter letter-u">U</li>`is not valid , ul can only have li for direct-child, , then i would say, if you use grid, no need of extra markup anyway , use grid power ;) grid and scale could do something alike : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/yLLVNNK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `transform: scaleX(n)` where 'n' is some amount of scale.

The same is true for trying to shrink the height of the 'u', using `transform: scaleY(n)` this time.

As for implementation, I personally think that using an svg would be better, as this font doesn't quite match the cover, you can see from the way the 'N' touches on the left but not the right on the album cover.

But if you wanted to manipulate the font, just know that `transform` can help you, and it has options other than just 'scale'.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
}

p {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.unity-cover {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 2fr 2fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "start-row"
    "end-row";
    justify-items: center;
}

.start-row {
    grid-area: start-row;
    display: flex;
}

.end-row {
    grid-area: end-row;
    display: flex;
}

.letter {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 1px;
    font-size: 23rem;
}

.letter-u {
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    top: 34px;
    left: -28px;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    transform: scaleY(0.97);
}

.letter-n {
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    transform: scaleX(1.22);
    vertical-align: baseline;
    top: 36px;
    left: -24px;
}

.letter-i {
    height: 300px;
}

.letter-t {
    height: 300px;
}

.letter-y {
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    right: 40px;
}
```

```html
<body>

        <ul class="unity-cover">
            <div class="start-row">
                    <li class="letter letter-u">U</li>
                    <li class="letter letter-n">N</li>
            </div>

            <div class="end-row">
                    <li class="letter letter-i">I</li>
                    <li class="letter letter-t">T</li>
                    <li class="letter letter-y">Y</li>
            </div>


        </ul>

</body>
```

Comment: I don't see how this actually scales the text. It scales the container element, but that doesn't change the aspect ratio of the text.

Comment: @isherwood When you apply `transform` to a container, it affects all the child components in it. You can see how the 'N' character is wider in my example, compared to the OP, when you run the code snippet.

Comment: Right you are. Your example has such small scale differentials that it's not apparent. My initial tests didn't seem to work, but clearly it does with [a more dramatic example](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/h4xpvg36/).

Comment: @isherwood yeah, you can really see it if you do something like `skew` an entire paragraph of text. But yes, this code is only subtle.

Comment: Wow that rules and its very close to what I needed except i just noticed another slight variation of this letter which would include i guess a path on SVG (?) or something.. it looks as if the second leg of the N is being lifted up just a little bit so the only thing touching the letters beneath it's just the first leg.

Comment: @Eduardo Yeah, that's why I say I would personally use an svg for the whole thing, that way it just matches the design exactly.

Comment: I know, only that would beat the purpose of it, I am trying to see if just by aligning a rectangle in between that space would do the trick.

Comment: @Eduardo Yeah, no reason at all that you couldn't do that. Just position the div and give a positive `z-index` so it appears over the 'N'. If you're happy with my answer to stretching font sizes, then feel free to accept it :)

Comment: about div being direct child of ul is no trouble to anyone ? what's the point of grid then ? look https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/details/yLLVNNK no divs ;)

Comment: @G-Cyr Haha, I'm not out here trying to fix every bit of code for best practices, just trying to answer the question at hand. I wouldn't use a list for this at all, a paragraph with spans would do a much better job and be far more accessible ;)

Comment: @BrettEast by clicking the upwards arrow is accepting an answer? Sorry im not too familure with the system - I just did. Thanks for the replying!

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the CSS transform property which has a scale() function. I've changed your CSS code a little bit and I think this is what you were going for:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
}

p {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.unity-cover {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 2fr 2fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "start-row"
    "end-row";
    justify-items: center;
}

.start-row {
    grid-area: start-row;
    display: flex;
}

.end-row {
    grid-area: end-row;
    display: flex;
}

.letter {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 1px;
    font-size: 23rem;
}

.letter-u {
    height: 315px;
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
}

.letter-n {
    height: 315px;
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
    right: 15px;
    transform: scaleX(1.2) scaleY(1.1);
}

.letter-i {
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    left: 25px;
}

.letter-t {
    height: 300px;
}

.letter-y {
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    right: 45px;
}
```